# Encoding php file

Tags: php, obfuscation, encode

I am looking for free php encoder/obfuscator.  Looked at http://adromil.myxednotes.com/ the output is nice, but it uses a script file pencode.php how hard to decode this page, it uses,

```
eval()
gzinflate()
str_rot13()
base64_decode()
```

If i encode a file with this script, How much difficult to decode the same provided that the pencode.php will be distributed along with the php files.

Can someone show how to reverse engineer using the same functions mentioned above,

content of pencode.php,

```
<?php $f='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'; eval(gzinflate(str_rot13(base64_decode('WC1YzNFVr8rMWMtWLFbVKC4pii/KLzE01lVXLEE1M4lCVlrOQlbVQ1bTBAJ4AA==')))); ?>
```

Comment: That's not obfuscation. That's basic encoding. Obfuscation is valid code that looks like crap.

Comment: Besides, why obfuscate the _PHP_ code? It never reaches the client unless you tell your server to interpret `.php` as plain text

Comment: @ColeJohnson Obfuscation of PHP code can be useful if you want to or have to distribute your code and do not want it to be modified.

Comment: i am going to give the php files, i want the page is encoded form so that they do not use for any other purpose of modify it.

Comment: @tmuguet why distribute obfuscated code?

Comment: @ColeJohnson So that it can be ran but not modified (or reverse-engineered) by a client? If a software written in PHP is not open-source, it doesn't mean it can't be distributed ;)

Comment: Decoding the sample that you provided is trivial. Incidentally, you do not need to pass an IV when you're using mcrypt in ECB mode.

Answer (score 0):

i can decode this

```
<?php
/**
*
* @ By Mr.Dm4r 
* @ http://hotm-il.com
*
*/

/*
*
*
*
* @summary     IRCI Political CRM
* @description Security encryption function
* @version     1.3.0
* @file        pencode.php
* @author      Ilios Resources and Cosultancy, Inc. (http://ilios-resources.com)
* @contact     http://ilios-resources.com/contactus.php
*
* @copyright Copyright 2012 Ilios Resources and Cosultancy, Inc., all rights reserved.
*
* This source file is free software, under either the GPL v2 license or a
* BSD style license, available at:
*   eula.txt
*   eula.pdf
* 
* 
* For details please refer to: http://ilios-resources.com
*
*/

function php_decrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
    return rtrim(
        mcrypt_decrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
            $sSecretKey, 
            base64_decode($sValue), 
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
            mcrypt_create_iv(
                mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                    MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                ), 
            MCRYPT_RAND
        )
    ), "\0"
    );
}

function php_encrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
    return rtrim(
    base64_encode(
            mcrypt_encrypt(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                $sSecretKey, $sValue, 
                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 
                mcrypt_create_iv(
                    mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
                        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                    ), 
                    MCRYPT_RAND)
                )
            ), "\0"
        );
}

function tokenf($algo='         adler32         ', $bsixfour='                  ODc0NzUzNTQ2Ng==               ', $bool=false) {
    return strtoupper(hash(trim($algo), trim($bsixfour), $bool));
}

function machineid() {
    $zv='snefru';
    $v='tiger128,4';
    $data = hash($zv, gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);
    return strtoupper(hash($v, $data, false));
}
?>
```